# Show Load Spinner when make POST API by JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add `load spinner` when click on `Add` And remain visible until the completion of `POST` then get `alert` Item has been added successfully.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
        fetch("url")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => setTimeout(function(){
            location.reload(alert("Item has been added successfully"));
        },1250))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
});
```

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce your problem with the snippet you provided. Consider editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it simply by putting your `showSpinner()` function (created by you to show the spinner) before the `fetch` commands, and then another function to hide the spinner before the alert.

Something like that:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
        showSpinner();
        fetch("url")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => setTimeout(function(){
            hideSpinner();
            location.reload(alert("Item has been added successfully"));
        },1250))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
});
```

Comment: Great ... this work with me 
but ( location.reload(alert("Item has been added successfully")) ) not work with me

Answer (score 1):

To display the spinner, you need to use a gif file for display spinner. In the below code you just need to replace the image src attribute with the actual spinner gif path.

You can try this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function() {
    // Show Spinner
    $('<span class="spinner-section"><img src="add gif path here" alt="Please wait..." width="30px" /></span>').insertAfter($(this)); 
    fetch('https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/')
    .then(response => response.json()).then(result => setTimeout(function(){
        // Remove Spinner
        $('.spinner-section').remove();
        location.reload(alert("Item has been added successfully"));
    },1250))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="add">Test Button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personally I use an svg or sprite, and then rotate() inside an animation.

Comment: If you have access to Font Awesome, they have build-in spinners too.